# Exception Classification in ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have put all my logs into ELK. I want to classify my exceptions according to the exception type. Example:
I want to classify the exceptions into "NullPointerException", "IndexOutOfBoundException",...

I have tried using the approach mentioned by @Val in the below previous question

[match_only_text fields do not support sorting and aggregations elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72100755/match-only-text-fields-do-not-support-sorting-and-aggregations-elasticsearch/76876163)

After following the steps mentioned by @Val using Kibana DevTools, I have created a filebeat scripted field using the script:

`if (doc.containsKey('message.keyword'))`

`{      if(doc['message.keyword'].size()>0)`

`{`

`def message = doc['message.keyword'].value;`

`if (message.contains("java.lang.IllegalStateException"))`

`return "Error-1";`

`else`

`return "Error-2";`

`}`

`}`

`else`

`return "No Message";`

It worked for the single line logs but didn't work for the multi-line logs. How can i make it work for the multi-line logs as well.

I will be glad if there is any better approach.

Comment: The [`categorize_text` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-categorize-text-aggregation.html) should be able to help you with this. Time permitting, I'll provide an example

Comment: Thank you for pointing out to the resource. I will be waiting to get an example/answer as I am completely new to the ELK stack.

Comment: You can already have a glimpse from this article: https://www.elastic.co/blog/categorize-your-logs-with-the-new-elasticsearch-categorize-text-search-aggregation

Comment: `POST filebeat-*/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
  "aggs": {
    "categories": {
      "categorize_text": {
        "field": "message"
      }
    }
  }
}`
Would this be a good one to automatically categorise logs @Val

Comment: Feel free to try it out along the lines of what's presented in those articles, time permitting I'll try to provide some guidance